# tensorflow ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
y = [0,1]
z = [1,2]
x = tf.constant(x)
y = tf.constant(y)
z = tf.constant(z)
m = x[y,z]
```

What I expect is `m = [2,6]`

I can get the result by theano or numpy. How I get the result using tensorflow?

Comment: I think It is not a tensorflow problem, event in python doesn't work. if you define x is a list and you cant access to a list as you want. Define x as numpy.array( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) and it will work.

Comment: Same with numpy array, my comment is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to use [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather_nd)

```
   slices = tf.gather_nd(x, [y, z])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you,I use tf.pack() and tf.gather_nd() get the result.

Comment: But then I get the error of Gradient for gather_nd is not implemented. T_T,So anyway else, Thank you